# Run angular with SSR and serve pages with https

Tags: angular, https, server-side-rendering

I am running the angular Heroes app, on SSR, by using

```
   ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

however, i am unable to get the server to serve pages over https

I have tried

```
  yarn dev:ssr --ssl
```

I know, how to run the non-SSR version of the angular app over https, just not the SSR version

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

With SSR your application runs over express server.
So you need to set SSL at the express server configuration.

First you need to generate your local certifications. Suggest using openSSL.

Create a certification.cnf configuration file:

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
x509_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = dn[dn]
C = GB
ST = London
L = London
O = My Organisation
OU = My Organisational Unit
emailAddress = email@domain.com
CN = localhost[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

Then run this command:
`openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout localhost.key -days 3560 -out localhost.crt -config certificate.cnf`

This will generate a `localhost.key` and a `localhost.crt`, that we put at a *ssl* folder at root application.

Finally change `run()` function at `server.ts` file with this:

```
import * as https from 'https';
import * as fs from 'fs';
[...]
function run(): void {
    const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;
    
    // https certificates
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('ssl/localhost.key');
    const certificate = fs.readFileSync('ssl/localhost.crt');
    // Start up the Node server
    const server = https.createServer({ key: privateKey, cert: certificate }, app());

    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Node Express server listening on https://localhost:${port}`);
    });
}
```

Because we need to use **https** module, one need to install it:
`npm install -s https`

For a complete tutorial see [here](https://medium.com/@dnlcyan/local-angular-ssr-with-https-b9d305dc620d).